# Why the suicide_no column are not in descending order?

Tags: sql, rank, partition

Good morning all,

This is my first ever question to this wonderful community. I'm learning SQL and got stuck in something.

Why is the column of suicides_no is not in descending order? Did I make a mistake in my SQL query? Please let me know.

```
select age, sex, suicides_no,
Rank() OVER(partition by sex order by suicides_no DESC) as Rnk
from dbo.suicide
where country = 'united kingdom'
AND year = 2010
```

| age | sex | suicides_no | Rnk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 75+ years | female | 89 | 1 |
| 35-54 years | female | 400 | 2 |
| 5-14 years | female | 3 | 3 |
| 55-74 years | female | 232 | 4 |
| 25-34 years | female | 133 | 5 |
| 15-24 years | female | 106 | 6 |
| 55-74 years | male | 696 | 1 |
| 25-34 years | male | 513 | 2 |
| 15-24 years | male | 344 | 3 |
| 75+ years | male | 227 | 4 |
| 35-54 years | male | 1444 | 5 |
| 5-14 years | male | 1 | 6 |

Comment: what data type is `suicides_no`? from your result I'm guessing it's a varchar rather than int type.

Answer (score 1):

put order by in that query

```
select age, sex, suicides_no,
Rank() OVER(partition by sex order by suicides_no DESC) as Rnk
from dbo.suicide
where country = 'united kingdom'
AND year = 2010 order by suicides_no ASC

 select age, sex, suicides_no,
Rank() OVER(partition by sex order by suicides_no DESC) as Rnk
from dbo.suicide
where country = 'united kingdom'
AND year = 2010 order by suicides_no DESC
```